# How do I add 4 Panels to my Frame ordered from top to bottom in java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

Thanks Guys! I got it to work. The links to the tutorials were very helpful.

I am trying to align 4 panels from top to bottom on my frame, I am just learning java. I can get 3 of them on there but want to add some texts above my buttons.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class ShowWindow extends JFrame
{

final int WIDTH = 650;
final int HEIGHT = 550;
private static JPanel buttonpanel;
private JButton button1;
private JButton button2;
private JButton button3;

public ShowWindow()
{   
GreetingPanel banner = new GreetingPanel();
Display getName = new Display();
Select select = new Select();
Select1 message = new Select1();

setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
setTitle("This is my window");
setVisible(true);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setIconImage((new ImageIcon("logo.jpg")).getImage());
getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);


add(banner, BorderLayout.NORTH);

add(getName, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Here is the part I need help with.
    add(message);

```
add(select, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

pack();

}
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Does it go off- frame? If so, just make it larger or add a JScrollPane

Comment: Use a box layout or any of the grid layouts. Check the javadocs (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/package-summary.html). Also see this tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: The problem isn't that it goes off frame or anything like that. The problem is the message panel won't show up at all. If I change things around I can make it show up instead of one of the other panels so I am sure the problem isn't in  the panels class. I tried    setLayout(new GridLayout(4,0)); but that didn't work either.

Comment: You can't use a BorderLayout, with 4 separate components because it only has space for 3 components to be added vertically. You could create a second panel (called "center") that uses another border layout. Then you can add two panels to the "center" panel and then add the "center" panel to your main frame. Or if you only want to use a single panel then you need to use a different layout manager. Read the tutorial link to better understand how a BorderLayout works.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a [`GridLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)

For example...

```
setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
```

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels save those up, I'll see of I can do something amazing to earn one ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use a box layout or any of the grid layouts. Check the javadocs (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/package-summary.html). Also see this tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: +1, for a link to the tutorial so the OP can read up on layout managers. We don't have enough information to recommend one layout manager over the other. BoxLayout or GridLayout are reasonable suggestions